Expectation of Non-Isotropic Projection Matrix
Let $\Pi$ be a projection matrix (i.e. $\Pi^2=\Pi$) derived from a random sample ($X$) which is from a $N(0,\Sigma)$ distribution. That is, $\Pi = X^T(XX^T)^{-1}X$. I am looking at figuring out $E[{\Pi}]$. In the isotropic case, this is well known. But I cannot find a reference for other case.
My intuitive notion would be that because the eigenvectors of $X^TX$ (and $\Pi$) converge to the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$, $E[\Pi]$ would have the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$. Further, as each eigenvector would have a $\frac{\lambda_i}{tr(\Sigma)}$ chance of appearing in $\Pi$, I would expect that over $n$ samples, the coefficient for each eigenvector would be $\frac{n\lambda_i}{tr(\Sigma)}$ (this also would preserve the trace through the expectation as needed).
